# Identify which replicant docker container is running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, replication

I need to identify the IP address (or ID) of the container when there are replicated Docker containers hosted. Is there any code snippet or tool for that? (I need to know which replicant container is being used at the moment.)

I done some search and found following,

```
docker inspect <container_name_or_id> --format='{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.